# Serving directory on samba share with Apache 2.4.41 truncates header

Tags: apache, samba

I have a strange problem when downloading files from an Apache 2.4.41 webserver serving files from a samba share on Ubuntu 20.04.

A python requests call ends in BadStatusLine('pache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)\r\n')) and Chrome sometimes shows partial http headers in the begining of the file.

Usually the response would start with "HTTP/1.1" while with this server it directly starts with "pache 2.4.41" which looks like a shortened "Apache 2.4.41".

After digging a lot I found one helpful post: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=900821

If I set "EnableSendfile On" in Apache for this directory it now seems to work. But this is scary as hell. Will it always work? Also for file uploads, etc.? Why is this still an issue in 2021 when the original error was reported in 2018!

And here the server response:

[image]

Comment: Another report about this problem I found: https://serverfault.com/questions/1044724/apache2-sends-corrupt-responses-when-using-a-cifs-share

Comment: The bug is now also reported in Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1930921